# Linkedin fetching user info not working in react js and nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, linkedin-api

This is the frontend code to send get request for the access token, where code is the parameter which we get after signing in from LinkedIn, I have checked that this code variable is getting sent properly so it has no issues.

```
const getAccessToken = async (code) => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/getaccesstoken/${code}`)
        console.log(response)
    }
```

This is the backend code

```
router.get('/getaccesstoken/:code', async (req, res)=>{
axios({
    method: "post",
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: { "Content-type": "x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    url: `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=${req.params.code}&client_id=${process.env.client_id}&client_secret={process.env.client_secret}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard`
})
    .then(function (response) { 
        console.log(response)
        res.send(response) 
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.send(error)
    })    
})
```

The error I am getting is the console of backend is very big but the last part says this:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"
```

}
but I am sending the request as soon as it is redirected so the code can't be expired so soon. And when I directly try doing this by passing code using thunderclient request it works fine.
Please let me know solutions to this if possible

Comment: I tried doing the same request in the frontend directly but got the same error, so I shifted it to the backend thinking it might work

Comment: Take a look at the actual URL you are generating. The syntax highlighting on stack overflow provides a hint because not everything became variable. You REALLY SHOULD NOT do string concatenation like this though. Use a OAuth2 library or at least URLSearchParams to generate the string